# How to take screenshot with alert box present in page [selenium python]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to take screenshot with alert box present in page using python
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: is not duplicate question

Comment: please read my question , my question is different

Comment: I need to take screenshot with alert box in page @jack